# DIVs wrapping, even with "display: inline-block"

Tags: html, css

I've got a few divs (multi-column page) with "display: inline-block" set. Shouldn't this prevent them from wrapping? I want them all side by side:

```
div.LabelColumn
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 0 0 40px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

div.DataColumn
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 0 0 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

To clarify, I want the DIVs side by side – i.e., shown as columns. I want them each to take up as much room as they need. Each of them, using what I want to display, should only take up about 100px, so there is easily enough room to display a few columns side by side. The first column will have a label, the second a bit of data, the third a label, and the fourth a bit of data.

To give a higher level view of the page, I have a div which I am floating left. To its right, I want the multiple columns of data. By the way, this is working in Chrome, but not in IE.

I would like the width to automatically adjust to be as wide as the text in the DIV, if possible.

Comment: it will prevent them from stacking if that is what you mean? Otherwise you might have to explain in more detail. Your code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mYAG6/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove inline block, use floating, assign width, and padding margin.[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WhrjL/1/)

Comment: Looks like I can leave off "width" and each DIV will take up only as much space as it needs.

Comment: In your demo, the divs still wrap to the next line when the browser window is resized.

Answer (score 4):

Using `inline-block` does not prevent elements from wrapping. In fact, when applied to `div` elements it will do the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

use `float`. for more information: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 0):

If you want them all side by side, their containing element needs to have enough width to allow so. You can prevent wrapping causing breaks within the elements by applying whitespace: nowrap;, but this may have other effects depending on how you've structured your markup.